# Stageros: cannot change z coordinate of base_link → base_laser tf

Tags: simulation, stage, stageros, base-link, base-laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
for any reason I cannot put the laser of my robot at its real height in the Stage-simulated version. The maximum z I get is 0.15 m! No idea why. I have tried to resize the robot model, to place the laser higher than real position, and more, but nothing helps. Is not a critical issue but annoying, as it force me to keep two different versions of costmap sensors configuration (simulated and real).

Here is my robot model (a turtlebot):

```
define kinect ranger
(
  sensor
  (
    range_max 6.5
    fov 58.0
    samples 640
  )
  # generic model properties
  color "black"
  size [ 0.06 0.15 0.03 ]
)

define turtlebot position
(
  pose [ 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ]

  odom_error [0.03 0.03 999999 999999 999999 0.02]

  size [ 0.33 0.33 0.40 ]
  origin [ 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ]
  gui_nose 1
  drive "diff"
  color "gray"
  
  kinect(pose [ -0.1 0.0 0.3 0.0 ])
)
```

And the base_link → base_laser tf:

```
- Translation: [-0.100, 0.000, 0.150]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
```

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62038/stageros:-cannot-change-z-coordinate-of-base_link-%E2%86%92-base_laser-tf/) by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2284 on 2013-05-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-05-03**:
If you change '0.3' in line 'kinect(pose [ -0.1 0.0 0.3 0.0 ])', Doesn't Translation change?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-05-03**:
Nop...  surprisingly z-value keeps being 0.15 regardless whatever I put on pose.z. I wonder if it's just a limitation of the code.

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-05-04**:
have you tried to define a block within kinect model?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-05-05**:
I have tried just now and doesn't helps:
define kinect ranger
(
...
block
(
size [ 0.06 0.15 0.03 ]
pose [ 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 ]
gui_nose 0
color "red"
)
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This problem is fixed on stage hydro

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1